# TFTP client cannot find PXE boot configuration file

Tags: tftp

I have set up DHCP and TFTP servers to allow boot via network. 
My server is 192.168.10.50 and the client is 192.168.10.51

The client gives me this:

```
Searching for server (DHCP)...
Me: 192.168.10.51, DHCP: 192.168.10.50, TFTP: 192.168.10.50, GATEWAY: 192.168.10.50 
Loading 192.168.10.50:pxelinux.0 ...(done)
...
TFTP prefix:
Unable to locate configuration file

Boot failed
```

On the server side, the syslog says:

```
testserver dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.10.51 to 52:54:00:28:90:f6 via eth1
testserver tftpd: trying to get file: pxelinux.0
testserver tftpd: serving file from /var/lib/tftpboot
testserver tftpd: trying to get file: pxelinux.cfg/default
testserver tftpd: serving file from /var/lib/tftpboot
```

If I do `ls -l /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg`, I get:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 23 11:59 default
```

i.e., the file exists and is readable. Can anyone tell me why the tftp client fails to boot?

Comment: You can exit the pxe menu using the ESC key. This will help bring your server back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path seems a bit wrong to me.
Try to create a folder named `pxelinux.cfg`.

In that, the config-file named `default` should reside, ie (in your case):

```
/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
```

The whole path (to/including `default`) needs to be world readable.

Comment: The default configuration file is called `default`. The OP has the correct path and filename, but I agree with you that it might be a permissions issue.

Comment: @muru ...post corrected, please undo the downvote.